# Problem in opening an Activity from Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android

I have created a Fragment view in my Navigation Drawer and
I want to call an Activity from that Fragment view using an ImageView for that I have written this java code in My Fragment View class
But I don't know why whenever I click on my image the app gets crashed please help out

```
package com.example.gamesense.ui.Maps;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.gamesense.R;

public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {
    private MapsViewModel mapsViewModel;
    private ImageView erangle_image;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mapsViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MapsViewModel.class);
            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

            //on click listener for image

            erangle_image = root.findViewById(R.id.erangle_image);
            erangle_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),ErangleMap.class));
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

}
```

And here is the XML for Fragment View and
from ImageView I want to open new Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.Maps.MapsFragment">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/erangle"
       android:background="@drawable/shape">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="200dp"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:id="@+id/erangle_image"
          android:src="@drawable/erangel"/>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="ERANGLE:"
          android:textAlignment="viewStart"
          android:background="#C59507"
          android:textSize="24sp"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:paddingTop="7dp"
          android:paddingLeft="15dp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#C59507"
          android:paddingBottom="10dp"
          android:text="Erangel is the first 8x8 km playable map created for PUBG."
          android:textAlignment="textStart"
          android:paddingLeft="15dp"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:textSize="18sp" />
   </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Logcat

````
2021-03-23 09:48:47.556 10047-10047/com.example.gamesense E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2021-03-23 09:48:47.586 10047-10086/com.example.gamesense E/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
2021-03-23 09:48:47.596 10047-10047/com.example.gamesense D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-03-23 09:48:47.597 10047-10047/com.example.gamesense E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gamesense, PID: 10047
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gamesense/com.example.gamesense.ui.Maps.ErangleMap}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3866)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8202)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:843)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.gamesense.ui.Maps.ErangleMap.onCreate(ErangleMap.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8146)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8130)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3668)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3866) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8202) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006) 
2021-03-23 09:48:47.623 10047-10047/com.example.gamesense I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10047 SIG: 92021-03-23 09:48:47.556 10047-10047/com.example.gamesense E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2021-03-23 09:48:47.586 10047-10086/com.example.gamesense E/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
2021-03-23 09:48:47.596 10047-10047/com.example.gamesense D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-03-23 09:48:47.597 10047-10047/com.example.gamesense E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gamesense, PID: 10047
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gamesense/com.example.gamesense.ui.Maps.ErangleMap}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3866)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8202)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:843)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.gamesense.ui.Maps.ErangleMap.onCreate(ErangleMap.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8146)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8130)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3668)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3866) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8202) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006) 
2021-03-23 09:48:47.623 10047-10047/com.example.gamesense I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10047 SIG: 9```
````

Comment: show your logcat

Comment: yup I have added logcat in question check out

Comment: refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/9382531

Comment: please add your 'manifest' and 'styles.xml'.

Answer (score 1):

it says "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."
maybe you edited/removed the theme by mistake. check your manifest

Comment: yes I have also added a theme to this class it worked thanks bro

Comment: you are welcome. We are all here for each other.
Happy Learning Happy codding :)

Answer (score 0):

have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? check this one Check your manifest first and declare your activity

Comment: Actually bro I have shared the wrong logcat now check out the new one I have updated it

Comment: show your ErangleMap activity and xml and also style where you are setting your theme

Comment: Actually, I forgot to add theme in manifest but now I have added it and it is working properly thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

Add or modify existing `theme` with `AppCompat` theme in your `styles.xml`. like the following:

```
<style name="yourThemeName" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat....">
    //.... items will go here
</style>
```

And you can use this `theme` as `global theme`

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/yourThemeName">
```

**OR**

For `specific activity`

```
<activity
    android:name=".ErangleMap"
    android:theme="@style/yourThemeName">
    //.... 
</activity>
```